# getDisplayCutout() returns null if emulated Tall cutout

Tags: android, android-cutout

1. Enable dev mode on device.
2. Emulate cutout (chose "Tall cutout" option).
3. `getWindow().getDecorView().getRootWindowInsets().getDisplayCutout()` returns `null`.

But for "Double cutout" it returns correct result.

**Device:** Pixel 3 with Android 10.